# Evaluating the expression 1 <= month <= 12

Tags: java, javascript, expression

I'm trying to evaluate expression `(1 <= month <= 12)` in a if condition.

This statement seems valid in javascript, but not in Java.

In Java,

```
int month = 0;
boolean flag = (1 <= month <= 12);
```

It throws following error:

> The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int

In Javascript,

```
var month = 0;
console.log('Expression evaluates to: ', (1 <= month <= 12));
```

> It always returns `true` no matter what the value of month is.

Can someone please explain:

- If it is a valid expression or not?
- Why does it always yield to `true` in javascript?
- Why does java consider it as an invalid expression?

Also I know I can get it to work it this way `(1 <= month && month <= 12)`. So, not looking for a solution but an explanation.

Thanks. Also let me know if my questions are not clear.

Comment: That's a valid expression (in JavaScript, not Java), but it doesn't do what you think it does. Java won't let you perform a comparison like that between a number and a boolean, but it parses the expression the same way (`(1 <= month) <= 12`).

Comment: Dont compare Javascript and Java. There are not made for the same purpose. Java is strongly typed, javascript is not and will allow more *funky* style programming

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<=` is non-associative, so you can't use it by repetition. You can specify it with:

```
1 <= month && month <= 12
```

The reason is that the *JavaScript parser* parses `1 <= month <= 12` as:

```
(1 <= month) <= 12
```

It's a consequence of the grammar of JavaScript, they could have defined it otherwise, but it would complicate the matter a bit. Most grammars define the expressions as:

```
expr -> [0-9]+
expr -> identifier
expr -> expr '<=' expr
```

(with an LALR) parser.

And *Java* uses the following (approximate) grammar:

```
expr -> numExpr '<=' numExpr
expr -> numExpr
numExpr -> identifier
numExpr -> [0-9]+
(...and so on...)
```

In Java it is thus even impossible to parse such expression (unless you perform a cast which makes it a `numExp` again).

---

**For the JavaScript part, why does it always return `true`?**

Now `(1 <= month)` is a boolean (true/`1` or false/`0`), and that value cannot be compared (reasonable) with `12` (`0` and `1` are always less than or equal to `12`). Only very limited programming languages support such feature.

Comment: *"and that value cannot be compared (reasonable) with 12"* Sure it can. It's coerced to a number.

Comment: @squint: yes but in this context, it doesn't make any sense. Mathematically *a<b<c* means *b* is *sandwiched* between *a* and *c*.

Comment: @squint: and [tag:java] doesn't automatically coerce booleans to int's anyway.

Comment: Sure, but the context is JavaScript.

Comment: @squint: no, it is tagged javascript, but the entire question deals with Java and JavaScript together.

Comment: Your answer was describing how it's parsed in JavaScript `(1 <= month) <= 12`. Whatever... this is the trouble with bringing two languages into a question with an expectation that they should be at all similar. ;-)

Comment: @squint: indeed. They shouldn't have named *JavaScript* after *Java* they haven't much in common. Java is quite strongly typed, while *JavaScript* is dynamically typed.

Comment: I agree. Frankly I think the original *LiveScript* name was better and certainly less confusing!

Comment: @squint My intent was not to compare the 2 languages as they both are a lot different, but was just curious to know why the output was different. And as for the language name part - I too do feel _LiveScript_ was much better & to avoid confusion as well.

Comment: @iaL: It's understandable to use experiences in one language as a basis for understanding or comparing another as long as one realizes that there should be no expectation of similarity. So questions like *"Why does language A consider this valid but language B does not"* will always boil down to *"because they're different languages"*. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the subquestion

> Why does java consider it as an invalid expression?

It's because Java evaluates it the following way:

```
(1 <= month) <= 12
 boolean     <= int
```

Booleans and ints cannot be compared because of the type safety.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is due to [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (which is the method used by most programming languages to evaluate logical expressions). Essentially what happens is the expression is evaluated left-to-right and transformed along the way so...

```
1 <= month <= 12
```

Gets evaluated as:

```
(1 <= month) <= 12
```

Which either gives you:

```
true <= 12
/* or */
false <= 12
```

As you can see, in Java (since it is type-safe) you get a type error. Because you cant use the `<=` operator on a boolean. In JS, booleans are always `<=` to a number (you can test this in your console).

Hope that answers your question!